# GeoJSON files using too much memory?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, memory

I have about/more than 400 GeoJSON layer files in my QGIS project. When I checked the task manager memory, it displays qgis.bin.exe *32 using about 1,334,000 of CPU memory. I had another version earlier which used shapefile instead of GeoJSON, and I remember the memory doesn't go beyond 1 million.

Will it be safer to use shapefiles instead of GeoJSON for all my layers?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I already had shapefiles in my project before, but I reinstalled the software and cleaned the registry because of various dll errors/crashes. After reinstalling, I loaded the saved project to find several shapefile layers corrupted. Upon inspection, it appears cleaning the registry removed the unused .shx files of several shapefiles. I am planning to redownload the corrupted polygon layers, but I would not like the program to crash. I opted to use GEOJSON instead because I wanted to avoid my .shx files accidentally deleted. But the Task manager shows it using much memory.

Comment: GeoJSON is good for sharing small and/or simple-structured geodata, talk through an API or such, but not very good to work with. It is limited in its functionality and does not utilize indexing. There is also a lot of repitition etc.; Using GeoPackage, SpatiaLite or a PostGIS database is better. Shapefile might be better to work with than GeoJSON, but has also some other limitations.